# How to continue function if Django object can't be found

Tags: python, django

I want to check if an object exists - if it doesn't exist I want to still continue the function and not return a 404 error. How can  I achieve this?

```
def check(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        # print('Working') #prints
        id = request.POST.get('id')
        post = Post.objects.get(hash=id)

        obj = get_object_or_404(Post, post=post)
        if obj:
            # do stuff
        else:
            #do something else
```

The above code returns:

```
Not Found: /check/
[22/Jul/2018 01:15:03] "POST /check/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1729
```

Comment: What are trying to do if it doesn’t exist? Is `Post` a `model`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply catch the `Post.DoesNotExist` exception and do something else in the exception handler:

```
def check(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        id = request.POST.get('id')
        try:
            post = Post.objects.get(hash=id)
            # do stuff
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            # do something else
```

Comment: Some thing else is
 raise Http404()

Comment: Does the stack trace show that it is this code causing the `Http404` exception, or Is something else in your code causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

If you use this often then you could make it as function and save it in helpers.py

```
def get_or_none(model, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return model.objects.get(*args, **kwargs)
    except model.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

and use it as

```
post = get_or_none(Post, hash=id)
if post:
   #do something
else:
   #do other thing
```